# JSON Parsing and Robospice

Tags: android, json, robospice

I'm building an Android app using Robospice for communication over network. The resulting object returned from my server does not get deserialized properly. Here are the related classes:

UserRequest.java

```
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.octo.android.robospice.request.googlehttpclient.GoogleHttpClientSpiceRequest;

import roboguice.util.temp.Ln;
import trees.park.cal.smoke.models.UserList;

public class UserRequest extends GoogleHttpClientSpiceRequest<UserList>{

    private String baseUrl = "http://10.0.0.3:8181/users/";

    public UserRequest() {
        super(UserList.class);
    }

    @Override
    public UserList loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        Ln.d("Call web service " + baseUrl);
        HttpRequest request = getHttpRequestFactory()
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(baseUrl));
        request.setParser( new JacksonFactory().createJsonObjectParser() );
        HttpResponse response = request.execute();
        return response.parseAs( getResultType() );
    }
}
```

UserList.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserList extends ArrayList<User> {
}
```

User.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class User {

    @JsonProperty("id")private long id;
    @JsonProperty("email")private String email;
    @JsonProperty("password")private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty("id") long id, @JsonProperty("email") String email, @JsonProperty("password") String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

When `response.parseAs(getRequestType())` is called, an exception is raised with the following stack trace:

```
08-19 23:54:08.411  27117-27139/trees.park.cal.smoke E//DefaultRequestRunner.java:154﹕ 23:54:08.418 Thread-5533 An exception occurred during request network execution :
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:381)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:354)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
            at trees.park.cal.smoke.server.UserRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(UserRequest.java:27)
            at trees.park.cal.smoke.server.UserRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(UserRequest.java:12)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(CachedSpiceRequest.java:48)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner.processRequest(DefaultRequestRunner.java:150)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner$1.run(DefaultRequestRunner.java:217)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:647)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:739)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:381)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:354)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
            at trees.park.cal.smoke.server.UserRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(UserRequest.java:27)
            at trees.park.cal.smoke.server.UserRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(UserRequest.java:12)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(CachedSpiceRequest.java:48)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner.processRequest(DefaultRequestRunner.java:150)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner$1.run(DefaultRequestRunner.java:217)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to create new instance of class trees.park.cal.smoke.models.User because it has no accessible default constructor
            at com.google.api.client.util.Types.handleExceptionForNewInstance(Types.java:165)
            at com.google.api.client.util.Types.newInstance(Types.java:120)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:763)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:647)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:739)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:381)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:354)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
            at trees.park.cal.smoke.server.UserRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(UserRequest.java:27)
            at trees.park.cal.smoke.server.UserRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(UserRequest.java:12)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(CachedSpiceRequest.java:48)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner.processRequest(DefaultRequestRunner.java:150)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner$1.run(DefaultRequestRunner.java:217)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class trees.park.cal.smoke.models.User; no empty constructor
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at com.google.api.client.util.Types.newInstance(Types.java:116)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:763)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:647)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:739)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:381)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:354)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
            at trees.park.cal.smoke.server.UserRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(UserRequest.java:27)
            at trees.park.cal.smoke.server.UserRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(UserRequest.java:12)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(CachedSpiceRequest.java:48)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner.processRequest(DefaultRequestRunner.java:150)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner$1.run(DefaultRequestRunner.java:217)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

However, if I use the an `ObjectMapper` the deserialization happens flawlessly. An example can be found in my LoginActivity (which I just wrote for testing purposes):

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity{

    private SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(JacksonGoogleHttpClientSpiceService.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        String json = "[\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        \"id\": 1, \n" +
                "        \"email\": \"michaeldubyu@gmail.com\", \n" +
                "        \"password\": \"password\"\n" +
                "    }, \n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        \"id\": 2, \n" +
                "        \"email\": \"asdf@adsf.com\", \n" +
                "        \"password\": \"\"\n" +
                "    }, \n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        \"id\": 3, \n" +
                "        \"email\": \"paymahn1@gmail.com\", \n" +
                "        \"password\": \"\"\n" +
                "    }, \n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        \"id\": 4, \n" +
                "        \"email\": \"michaeasdfldubyu@gmail.com\", \n" +
                "        \"password\": \"password\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "]";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            UserList result = mapper.readValue(json, UserList.class);
            System.out.println("test");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //stuff
    }
}
```

If I manually replace the `response.parseAs(getRequestType())` with an ObjectMapper and manually get the input stream from the `HttpResponse` then I can deserialize the response perfectly.

Why can't the JsonObjectParser do what the ObjectMapper does? How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in stacktrace

Caused by: `java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class trees.park.cal.smoke.models.User;` **`no empty constructor`**

Try add contructor without parameters to `User` class

```
public User() {
}
```

Comment: Making the constructor `private` is sufficient for Jackson and keeps the exposed API clean.